# Excel 2013 Macro called by Loop through Macro works only on one Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Kindly excuse me for mistakes in posting and rules etc. I am Zero at Macro and posting at Forums.
In large database, I need to change color of few names.
First part of Macro I found on Microsoft Web Page. Second part I recorded.

The Macro runs only on one sheet. Despite extensive search, cant find answer.
Please guide , help, correct. I appreciate and thank you in advance.

```
Sub ChangeName_DifferentColor_Loop()

    'ChangeName_DifferentColor_Loop
    'Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.

    Dim Current As Worksheet
    'Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        Call ChangeName_DifferentColor_SingleSheet
        ' This line displays the worksheet name in a message box.
        MsgBox Current.Name
    Next
End Sub

-------------------------------
'Insert you Code Here.
Sub ChangeName_DifferentColor_SingleSheet()      '
    ' ChangeName_DifferentColor_SingleSheet Macro
    '
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A1048545").Activate
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
        Strikethrough = False
        Superscript = False
        Subscript = False
        color = 192
        TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.Replace What:="Mike", Replacement:="Mike", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=True
    Selection.Replace What:="Della", Replacement:="Della", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=True
    Selection.Replace What:="Ike", Replacement:="Ike", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=True
    Selection.Replace What:="Shan", Replacement:="Shan", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
                      ReplaceFormat:=True
    With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
        Strikethrough = False
        Superscript = False
        Subscript = False
        color = 255
        TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ReplaceFormat:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    enter code here
End Sub
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: Why not put the change name sub inside the for each loop in the first sub?

Comment: With the way you have the code, you would have to select the sheet before calling the macro

Comment: What range are you needing this to run on? Just all of Col A on each sheet?

Comment: Thank you a lot to every one for nice and quick help. I tried to put change name Macro inside the loop through Macro. id not work just because it gives errors that I do not understand even by reading the help. Macro by urdearboy seem to be working after i changed to " Set CurrentRange = Current.Range("A1:A" & LRow)" Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. You should avoid depending on `.Selection`. Instead, explicitly state a range. Here, the range will be Column A from `A1` to last used row in Col A (`LRow`). This range is refferred to as `CurrentRange` in the code.
2. You need to prefix your properties in the `With` statement with `.`
3. You can remove options in your `Replace` that are set to `False`. If not stated, they will default to `False`
4. Disable `ScreenUpdating` to speed up run time

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ChangeName_DifferentColor_Loop()

Dim Current As Worksheet
Dim LRow As Long
Dim CurrentRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Current In Worksheets
        MsgBox Current.Name

        LRow = Current.Range("A" & Current.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        CurrentRange = Current.Range("A1:A" & LRow)

            With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .Color = 192
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

                CurrentRange.Replace What:="Mike", Replacement:="Mike", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, ReplaceFormat:=True
                CurrentRange.Replace What:="Della", Replacement:="Della", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=True
                CurrentRange.Replace What:="Ike", Replacement:="Ike", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=True
                CurrentRange.Replace What:="Shan", Replacement:="Shan", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, ReplaceFormat:=True

            With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
                .Strikethrough = False
                .Superscript = False
                .Subscript = False
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With

    Next Current
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you urdearboy. Code works fine. I omitted some detail. What should be done if I need to chage name Ike to green (Color = 5287936), Della to yellow (Color = 49407), and Shan to Blue (Color = 15773696). Thank you again.

Comment: It will be privilege to see your guidance but I was successful in applying different colors to different name. It seems to be working well.